# List is returning item after deleting all the items

Tags: java, android

My List is returning an item after clearing all the items by deleting ,On app fresh install its returing null  which is good but after adding item and then by deleting all, this happens when go back from that activity and come again, list.size() is returning 1 and an item is remaing ,i don't know if it is loading from cache object instance here is my code of adapter class

```
public static  double p = 0;
private List<CartModel> cartModelList;
Database db;
Context context;

public CartAdapter(Context context, List<CartModel> cartModelList) {
    this.cartModelList = cartModelList;
    this.context = context;
    db = new Database(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_layout_item, parent, false);
    return new Viewholder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Viewholder holder, final int position) {


    String namee = cartModelList.get(position).getName();
    String manufacturere = cartModelList.get(position).getManufacturer();
    String availabilitye = cartModelList.get(position).getAvailability();
    String e_parte = cartModelList.get(position).getE_part();
    String m_parte = cartModelList.get(position).getM_part();
    String floatprice = cartModelList.get(position).getUnit_();
    String int_quantity = cartModelList.get(position).getQuantity();
    String float_line_total = cartModelList.get(position).getLine_total();



    holder.setItemDetails(namee, manufacturere, availabilitye, e_parte, m_parte, floatprice, int_quantity, float_line_total);


    int  checker = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).cartcount().getCounter();

    if (checker <= 0){

        cartModelList.clear();

    }

    holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (db.deleteProduct(cartModelList.get(position).getID())) {


                if (cartModelList.size() == 1){
                  cartModelList.clear();


                }else {
                    cartModelList.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                Toast.makeText(context, "Product  deleted from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Product not deleted from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            CartList user111 = new CartList(--COUNTER_BADGE);

            //  Toast.makeText(context, "else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).cartList(user111);
            ((Activity)context).invalidateOptionsMenu();
            ((Activity)context).finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CartActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }



    });

    holder.btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String q = holder.quantity.getText().toString();


            if(q.isEmpty()){
                holder.quantity.setError("Required Field");
                holder.quantity.requestFocus();


            }else {

                double q2 = Double.parseDouble(q);
                int avail = Integer.parseInt( cartModelList.get(position).getAvailability());
                int qty = Integer.parseInt(q);

                if (qty > avail ){
                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText( (context),
                            "Quantity must be less than the products Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();


                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, ""+cartModelList.get(position).getManufacturer(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String url = BASE_URL+"api/product/single_product?pnum="+cartModelList.get(position).getE_part();
                    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);


                    //String Request initialized
                    StringRequest mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {

                                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONObject products = result.getJSONObject("single_product");

                                final JSONArray Price = products.getJSONArray("price_range");


                                for (int i = 0; i < Price.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject attributes = null;
                                    try {
                                        attributes = Price.getJSONObject(i);


                                        try {
                                            int a = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getString("to")));
                                            int b = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getString("from"));


                                            if (qty >= b ) {


                                                p = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getString("price"));


                                                String pricee = String.valueOf(p);

                                                holder.price.setText("£"+pricee);


                                                double linetotal6 = qty * p;
                                                DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

                                                String roundoff = df2.format(linetotal6);
                                                holder.linetotal.setText("£"+roundoff);


                                            }
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                                            // Toast.makeText(ProductDescription.this, "Not a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }



                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }






                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+e);
                            }



                            holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Log.i(TAG, "Error :" + error.toString());

                            holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        public String getBodyContentType() {
                            return "application/json";
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            headers.put("Authorization", BASE_Token);
                            return headers;
                        }


                    };


                    mStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                            90000,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                    mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
                    holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(Database.Quantity,q);
                    values.put(Database.Line_total,q2 * p);
                    values.put(Database.Unit_price, p);
                    if(db.updateProduct(cartModelList.get(position).getID(),values)){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Product updated cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Product not updated from cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    ((Activity)context).finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CartActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    context.startActivity(intent);


                }

            }
        }
    });



    holder.adapter_livestock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String url = BASE_URL+"api/product/check_availability?data_id="+cartModelList.get(position).getE_part();//+forgot_code;

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);


            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {
                        //converting response to json object
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                        String status = obj.getString("status");



                        if (status.equals("ERROR")) {


                            Toast.makeText(context, status+""+obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        } else {

                            String livechecker = obj.getString("total_stock");
                        /*  //  cart_value.setText(livechecker + " \nIn stock");
                            cartModelList.get(position).getAvailability();*/

                            holder.availability.setText(livechecker);

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                    holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }) {


                //This is for Headers If You Needed
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Authorization", BASE_Token);
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

                    return params;
                }


            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            holder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cartModelList.size();
}

class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView name;
    private TextView manufacturer;
    private TextView availability;
    private TextView e_part;
    private TextView m_part;
    private TextView price;
    private EditText quantity;
    private TextView linetotal;
    private Button btn_delete;
    private Button btn_update;
    private  Button adapter_livestock;
    public  SpinKitView progressbar;

    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        manufacturer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
        availability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.availability);
        e_part = itemView.findViewById(R.id.e_part);
        m_part = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_part);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        linetotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linetotal);
        btn_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        btn_update = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
        adapter_livestock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_livestock);
        progressbar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adapterrprogresslivestockprogress);

    }


    private void setItemDetails(String namee, String manufacturere, String availabilitye, String e_parte, String m_parte, String floatprice, String int_quantity, String float_line_total) {

        name.setText(namee);
        manufacturer.setText(manufacturere);
        availability.setText(availabilitye);
        e_part.setText(e_parte);
        m_part.setText(m_parte);
        price.setText("£"+floatprice);
        quantity.setText(int_quantity);
        linetotal.setText("£"+float_line_total);


    }


}
```

}
this is my cart activity

```
Database db;
TextView subtotal, total;
private double mSubTotal = 0;
Button check_button;
Spinner cart_country;

String countryitemidsss;
String itemcountriesss;

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

SpinKitView cartProgressBar;
TextView cart_shipping1, cart_vat1;
String cart_shipping11, cart_vat11;

double myshiping = 0;
double myvat = 0;

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private StringRequest mStringRequest;
public static String subtoalvalue;




public static final String EXTRA_SUBTOTAL = "subtotal";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment); //Remember this is the FrameLayout area within your activity_main.xml
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, contentFrameLayout);


    subtotal = findViewById(R.id.subtotal);
    total = findViewById(R.id.total);
    check_button = findViewById(R.id.checkout_securely);

    cart_country = findViewById(R.id.cart_country);

    cartProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.cartProgressBar);

    cart_shipping1 = findViewById(R.id.cart_shiping);
    cart_vat1 = findViewById(R.id.cart_vat);

    db = new Database(this);


    ArrayAdapter<String> customSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    cart_country.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    cart_country.setAdapter(customSpinnerAdapter);


    db = new Database(this);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cart_recycler);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    List<CartModel> cartModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    cartModelList = db.getCarts();

    for (int i = 0; i < cartModelList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cartModelList.size(); j++) {
            if (cartModelList.get(i).getE_part().equals(cartModelList.get(j).getE_part())) {
                cartModelList.get(i).setM_part(cartModelList.get(j).getM_part());
                cartModelList.get(i).setName(cartModelList.get(j).getName());
                cartModelList.get(i).setQuantity(cartModelList.get(i).getQuantity());
                cartModelList.remove(j);
                j--;
                Log.d("remove", String.valueOf(cartModelList.size()));

            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cartModelList.size(); i++) {
        mSubTotal = mSubTotal + Double.parseDouble(cartModelList.get(i).getLine_total());


    }

    int counter33 = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).cartcount().getCounter();


    if(counter33 <= 0){

        LinearLayout caritemTrue = findViewById(R.id.cartItemTrue);

        caritemTrue.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
    else
        {

        LinearLayout cartitemempty = findViewById(R.id.cartItemEmpty);
        cartitemempty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    subtoalvalue = String.format("%.2f", mSubTotal);

    // Toast.makeText(this, subtoalvalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    subtotal.setText("£"+subtoalvalue);

    //  mSubTotal = mSubTotal;


    total.setText(String.valueOf(mSubTotal));

    CartAdapter cartAdapter = new CartAdapter(this, cartModelList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(cartAdapter);


    check_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isLoggedIn()) {

                Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Checkout.class);
                intent3.putExtra(EXTRA_SUBTOTAL, subtoalvalue);
                startActivity(intent3);



            } else {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckOutRegistration.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        }
    });

    if (cartModelList.size() == 0) {

        db.cleanCart();


    }

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // On selecting a spinner item


    countryitemidsss = ids.get(cart_country.getSelectedItemPosition());

    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ids.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    itemcountriesss = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


    sendAndRequestResponse();

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemcountries, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}


private void sendAndRequestResponse() {


    String url = BASE_URL+"api/customers/getvat?user_id=693&login=0&country=" + countryitemidsss + "&buying_as_company=1";

    //RequestQueue initialized
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    //String Request initialized
    mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);

                String status = result.getString("status");


                JSONObject businessObject = result.getJSONObject("data");
                cart_shipping11 = businessObject.getString("vat");
                cart_vat11 = businessObject.getString("shipping_charges");



                  shippping = data.getString("shipping_charges");
                    vaaat = data.getString("vat");*/


                cart_shipping1.setText("£"+cart_shipping11);
                cart_vat1.setText("£"+cart_vat11);

                myshiping = Double.parseDouble(cart_shipping11);
                myvat = Double.parseDouble(cart_vat11);
                totalCounter();

                // Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this,""+ myshiping+myvat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                try {


                    myshiping = Float.parseFloat(cart_shipping11);
                    myvat = Float.parseFloat(cart_vat11);
                } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Could not parse " + nfe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/


                cartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //  spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Checkout.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries));


        }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            cartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", BASE_Token);
            return headers;
        }


    };


    mStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            90000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
    // progressDialog.show();
    // mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
    cartProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}

private void totalCounter() {

    String total23 = String.valueOf(mSubTotal + myshiping + myvat);

    double fulltotal = Double.parseDouble(total23);
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    String roundoff = df2.format(fulltotal);

    total.setText("£"+roundoff);
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Re-post of [List size is returning item after clearing all the list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61097600/5221149)

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: but i am not geeting any answers